# how to print the logs for dependent jar file in java?

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I have developed an application which contains some data transfer logic from one database to other database and which is configured with `Log4j` to print the logs.
This application is running smoothly and print logs when it is running individually but when this project is made as jar and integrate as a dependent `jar` in some other `jar`.
I was not able see the logs printed for dependent `jar`, I am building the main application as a `jar` using `Ant (which will be build with dependent jar)`.
I am able to see logs for the main jar but not able see the log file generated for dependent `jar`.

Could any body tell me, how to print the logs for dependent jar file?

Comment: Is the dependent jar files contains logging statements? Because you are implementing logging for your application not for all the jars which you have incorporated

Comment: Yes, both of are my applications, I configured log4j for dependent jar and printing the logs.

Comment: You'll need to include more details. If the classes from both jars are both using the log4j logging API then we'd expect both to appear in the log output unless you've configured log4j to filter output.